# Deployed Smart contract methods are not updating the value when restart the geth instance.Why?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment, dapps

Started Geth using following command

```
geth --identity "testpvtnode" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir <pvtnetdatapath> --port "30303" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --networkid 123 console 2>> Logfile
```

Accessing the deployed contract through an UI created by referring the following links - ([counter](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/), [Stack Exchange Question related to UI creation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60592/how-to-interface-with-a-deployed-ethereum-smart-contract))

I have successfully created the UI and interacted with SmartContract, but the functions are not working properly(able to call the function and transaction done successfully,but counter value is not updating) after I restarted the Geth instance.

Please note : The private net is on my pc( did not set as a server)

Comment: have you mined the transactions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mine your transactions using :     `miner.start()`

you should wait for a while once mined you can stop mining process using `miner.stop()`

But before doing that you should load `miner` api using in geth command line :

```
--rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner
```

Comment: I have used `miner.start()` and `miner.stop` on my DApp code, but it is not executing (used as `web3.miner.start()` and `web3.miner.stop()`).The code stucks at `web3.miner.start()`. The same issue I am facing for `web3.personal.unlockAccount` also.So I always have to start the miner and unlock the account via geth console.Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: use miner.start and stop on your  geth console not on your code.

Comment: I am always doing like that only.But it is very difficult to do it on console everytime.why the api can not use in DApp Code?

Comment: you can use a script to automate mining https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10262/how-to-stop-mining-unwanted-blocks-on-private-net-on-geth-ethrereum

Comment: But I want to add the mining Api to my DApp code.